# Why are twisted subsheaves not subbundles?

Tags: algebraic-geometry, vector-bundles

Let $X$ be a projective variety over $\mathbb{C}$. If $F\subset E$ is a subbundle, then $F(-D)\subset E$ is a subsheaf, where $D$ is say an effective divisor on $X$ and $F(-D):=F\otimes \mathcal{O}_X(-D)$. Even though it's a subsheaf, why is $F(-D)$ not a subbundle of $E$ when $D\neq 0$? In the case $\mathcal{O}_X(-D)\subset \mathcal{O}_X$, it's not a subbundle because a line bundle does not have nonzero subbundles.

I know that generally, given locally free sheaves of $\mathcal{O}_X$-modules $\mathscr{G}$ and $\mathscr{H}$ such that $\mathscr{G}\subset\mathscr{H}$, though we have $0\rightarrow \mathscr{G}_x\rightarrow \mathscr H_x$ on the level of sheaves, tensoring with the residue field is not exact, and so we only have $$\cdots\rightarrow \operatorname{Tor}^1(k(x),\mathscr H_x/\mathscr G_x)\rightarrow G_x\rightarrow H_x\rightarrow\cdots$$ where $G_x=\mathscr{G}_x\otimes k(x)$ and $H_x=\mathscr{H}_x\otimes k(x)$. So if $\mathscr H_x/\mathscr G_x$ is not flat, we don't have that $G$ is a subbundle of $H$. I would also like to see how this fails explicitly in the case $F(-D)\subset E$ and $D\neq 0$. And how can I show that a line bundle doesn't have nontrivial subbundles using this setup?

Comment: Yes, $\mathcal{O}_X(-D)\subseteq \mathcal{O}_X$ is a subsheaf, but not a sub-bundle. This is because its cokernel is not locally free. In general, if $i:E_1\subseteq E_2$ is an inclusion of locally free sheaves, then $E_1$ is a sub-bundle of $E_2$ if and only if the sheaf cokernel $E_2/i(E_1)$ is locally free.

Comment: An injective map of locally sheaves corresponds to a map of vector bundles $f : E \to F$ that induces an injection on sections. One way that can happen is if $f$ is injective (in which case the image of $E$ is a subbundle of $F$), but that’s not the only way. For example if $f$ is dominant, or if $f$ is injective on almost all fibers. That’s the sort of thing that happens with a map like $O(-1) \to O$, it corresponds to a map of line bundles that is injective on the general fiber.

Comment: @AGlearner  What is the support of a quotient sheaf $V/L$ where $V$ is a rank two vector bundle and $L$ is a locally free rank 1 subsheaf of $V$?

Comment: The quotient sheaf has rank $1$ (but may have torsion), so the support is the whole variety.

Comment: @AGlearner But a coherent sheaf has torsion if and only if its support is not equal to the whole variety. Also in your first comment, I think it's enough to require the cokernel to be torsion-free (for $E_1$ to be a subbundle of $E_2$).

Comment: $\mathcal{O}_X\oplus \mathcal{O}_p$ is a sheaf with torsion which has support the whole variety.

Comment: @AGlearner You are right. The proposition was from https://arxiv.org/pdf/1905.07085.pdf p. 33. It's wrong because of that example.